# Does a firebase storage reference change on each invocation of storage#getReference()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase storage documentation recommends that a a storage reference should be stored in a bundle and restored on configuration change. Does this mean that storage#getReference() always returns a different instance on each invocation? I have the need to query the upload tasks associated with a storage reference in a service that does not have access to a reference created elsewhere. If the reference changes, then calling storage#getReference() in said service will have a different instance.

Comment: Storage references are actually lightweight objects, so I'm not sure why the documentation would recommend reusing them. Can you link me to the documentation that says that?

Comment: If you want to store a reference persistently, just store the string path of the reference, and pass that string to getReference when you need a StorageReference object for the object at that path.  A StorageReference is just a pointer to that location.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#handle_activity_lifecycle_changes

Comment: @ Doug Stevenson I get that. I'm wondering why there is such a need. I thought it's either because creating a storage reference is expensive or on every invocation of getReference() a new reference is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the docs. As far as I can read there it talks about persisting the path, not the reference (which is restores as needed with `storageRef = Firebase.storage.getReferenceFromUrl(stringRef)`). The reason you need to store the path is because in many cases the path is dynamically constructed in a way that can't be recreated (for example by putting a timestamp in there to ensure it's unique).

Comment: Okay, That makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

Storage references are lightweight objects, so there is no need to reuse them.

You may want to store the path, because in many cases the path is dynamically constructed in a way that can't be recreated (for example by putting a timestamp in there to ensure it's unique). You can then reconstruct the reference from the path in the way the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#handle_activity_lifecycle_changes) shows: `storageRef = Firebase.storage.getReferenceFromUrl(stringRef)`.

You can then find the active upload tasks for that reference (and path) with `val tasks = storageRef.activeUploadTasks`.

Comment: Okay, So I guess calling storage.getReference().getActiveUploadTasks() in different components will  give access to all active tasks without regard of the stringRef argument.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you should get all upload tasks for the path (regardless of whether its the same reference object), but I never tried it myself. It is something you shuold be able to test fairly easily though.